# Pulling Reports with Custom Fields

Tags: custom-fields, profile, civireport, custom-reports

Ok, I have a customer that has created an event that has a rather extensive profile setup, which includes a field to upload a file.

When they pull the report, the full URL to access the file isn't include, it just shows (  ).

Is it possible get the full URL to populate that field when you pull the report?

Thank You!!
Nicole

Comment: Sounds like this might be a bug. Is this a custom report? Can you reproduce it on the demo site using a standard report?

Comment: here is the code that didn't show previously :) - '<a href="/civicrm/file?reset=1&amp;id=19&amp;eid=2784">'

Comment: So are you saying there is an `<a>` tag with no content so it is not visible to the user?

Comment: there's an '<a>' tag, and it does have part of a URL for the file, but not the entire URL. It is just everything after the .org/ of the domain. Here is what it's pulling: [https://app.box.com/s/bw2wa8t0hw1a6keo3jg6pn2yisfz9uqe]

Comment: That should work fine, that's what internal links (e.g. from one page of your own website to another) usually look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you working in drupal? If so, I recommend using a custom view, rather than trying to get a custom report.